# Riverpod : The reason why "the number of rebuilds is the same when using ref.read and ref.watch" in the sample code of official documentation

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading/#dont-use-refread-inside-the-build-method

```
//bad example
final counterProvider = StateProvider((ref) => 0);

Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
  StateController<int> counter = ref.read(counterProvider.notifier);
  return ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () => counter.state++,
    child: const Text('button'),
  );
}
```

```
//good example
final counterProvider = StateProvider((ref) => 0);

Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
  StateController<int> counter = ref.watch(counterProvider.notifier);
  return ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () => counter.state++,
    child: const Text('button'),
  );
}
```

> Both snippets achieve the same effect: our button will not rebuild
> when the counter increments.

As explained above, why is there no difference in the number of rebuilds between these two samples?

According to the explanation before this, ref.watch is used in good-example, so I simply wonder if the button will be rebuilt when the counter increases.

Answer (score 0):

You should have `final counter = ref.watch(counterProvider);` if you want your widget to rebuild when the count changes.  Watching the notifier isn't very useful.

Comment: I have one doubt, Is there any difference between watching and reading a notifier?

Comment: Same difference as always between read and watch.  read gets current value, watch also sets up a listen for changes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

The sample code in my question is from the official Riverpod documentation.

I think the sample is intended to show that "you may want to use the read method to suppress unnecessary rebuilds, but that's not a good idea".

After all, the "good example" is also a less-than-desirable use case?